# Delta wing flow patterns (straight and yawing)

Tags: aerodynamics

I was wondering the differences between fluid patterns and their consequences when a delta wing is straight and yawed slightly. Thank you.

Comment: There are many resources on the web which help to answer this question, but not necessarily very recent ones. Take [NACA TN 2674](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1952/naca-tn-2674.pdf) which shows tufted delta wings, or [NACA Research Memorandum L57A30](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1957/naca-rm-l57a30.pdf). Replicating the content of those in an answer would indeed need some space, so it will be better to ask a more focused question.